# Trigger something on iframe click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Got a js that appends an iframe with content from other site. I need certain action to be triggered on click within the iframe.

Obviously, i can't use elements inside iframe. I've tried following, and it didn't work.

```
$('.container iframe').click(function(){
   alert('works!");
});
```

Then I tried this.

```
$('.container').click(function(){
   alert('works!");
});
```

click on container works, but when click happens within iframe, it doesn't work.

Can someone point me in right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. If you were able to listen for events on the content of the iframe, it would be open to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var iframeBody = $('body', $('.container iframe')[0].contentWindow.document);
    $(iframeBody).on('click', function(e) {
        // your code
    });
```